# unable to set width height property of Teaching tip in UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Hi I am trying set width, the height of  TeachingTip Class of UWP.
But it is not working. Anyone know what is going on. That will help.

Comment: Could you share more detail about   `TeachingTip ` class? I could  not find it in uwp platform.

Comment: Hi Nico Zhu Please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.teachingtip?view=winui-2.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> unable to set width height property of Teaching tip in UWP

The `TeachingTip` control will automatically set the size base on the content size, if you want to modify it please add an element into the `Content` property and set element with pertinent size.

```
<controls:TeachingTip         
    x:Name="ToggleThemeTeachingTip1"
    Title="Change themes without hassle"
    Subtitle="It's easier than ever to see control samples in both light and dark theme!"
    Target="{x:Bind ThemeButton}"
    >
    <controls:TeachingTip.IconSource>
        <controls:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Refresh" />
    </controls:TeachingTip.IconSource>
    <controls:TeachingTip.Content>
        <StackPanel Height="300">
            <TextBlock Text="t's easier than ever to see control samples in both light and dark theme!" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:TeachingTip.Content>
</controls:TeachingTip>
```

Please note that the `TeachingTip` control has size limits in its default sesttings, for more please refer [this](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TeachingTip/TeachingTip_rs1_themeresources.xaml#L33) .
These default values for max. and min sizes should be overrriden so that the dynanic sizing based on the content can work:

```
<x:Double x:Key="TeachingTipMinHeight">40</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="TeachingTipMaxHeight">520</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="TeachingTipMinWidth">320</x:Double>
<x:Double x:Key="TeachingTipMaxWidth">336</x:Double>
```

Comment: Hi, Nico, i have visited the given link and the problem in min-width specified is 320,I have a scenario in my project that i need to set this dynamically.So  is there any way we can override in page and use lesser width like 10,20 etc

Comment: Please try to  add the    `<x:Double x:Key="TeachingTipMinWidth">your width</x:Double>` to the app's application resource dictionary

Comment: Its Works Thanks Nico you save my day

Comment: @Nico: This worked also for the 'TeachingTip' control in WinUI (I suppose that is based on the USW version of the control)

Comment: @Nico Zhu, setting the TeachingTipMinWidth in App.xaml changes it everywhere, is there a way to only set it for certain UserControl?