# Unable to change the background colour of TeachingTip in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui

I am using the teaching tip control from WinUi 2.4 in UWP, Want to change the background color. But the background value i give in xaml is not reflecting in control.

```
 <winui:TeachingTip x:Name="ToggleThemeTeachingTip2"
  Title="Change themes without hassle"
  Subtitle="It's easier than ever to see control samples in both light and dark theme!"
  PreferredPlacement="Auto"
PlacementMargin="20"                    
IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
  Background="Red"
   >
```

- Here i gave the background value as red, but it is not reflecting in the control. I think it is taking only the default values, is there any way to override that default values and set our values like background color.
- saw some suggestions like in this example but it is not working [Changing default values of tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59542235/unable-to-set-width-height-property-of-teaching-tip-in-uwp) and [DefaultValues](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TeachingTip/TeachingTip_rs1_themeresources.xaml#L33)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that funny? Because it works when you set light dismiss to false.

Reason is here: https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/master/dev/TeachingTip/TeachingTip.xaml#L32

See that in `LightDismiss` state it forces the theme value.

So you need to copy and edit that style to respect TemplateBinding (the red color you set on control)

```xml
<VisualState x:Name="LightDismiss">
    <VisualState.Setters>
        <Setter Target="TailEdgeBorder.Background" Value="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <Setter Target="TailPolygon.Fill" Value="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <Setter Target="TopTailPolygonHighlight.Fill" Value="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <Setter Target="ContentRootGrid.Background" Value="{Binding Background,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
    </VisualState.Setters>
</VisualState>
```

I made it easier for you and sharing full `App.xaml` file with some namespace edits and so on:

https://pastebin.com/QgPpqMKS

Just change the x:class, mine is App9. Also note, that I commented the line with CornerRadius, because it throws some errors (??).

Also add style to your teaching tip:

```xml
 <winui:TeachingTip x:Name="ToggleThemeTeachingTip2"
  Title="Change themes without hassle"
  Subtitle="It's easier than ever to see control samples in both light and dark theme!"
  PreferredPlacement="Auto"
PlacementMargin="20"                    
IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
Style="{StaticResource MyTeachingTipStyle}"
  Background="Red"
   >
```